# How to assign runtime connection string to rdlc dataset in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, rdlc

We have a single `.rdlc` file for multiple users with different databases, so their connection string will be different.

[image]

i.e., Where .rdlc file is loading data from designed dataset TableAdapter and TableAdapter wizard is taking ConnectionString from web.config. 
We want to assign connection string runtime. How to change the connection string at runtime?

First we had designed DataSet(.xsd) file and add a Table Adapter

secondly we had designed .rdlc file as below

and then we had designed a report form which is .aspx page and from where we are calling GetData()

code is as below:

```
dt = new branchListTableAdapter().GetData(State, short.Parse(hfCpID.Value));
            if (dt != null)
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["Reportpara"] = "Branch_branchList/Reports/Branch.rdlc";
                    Session["Reports"] = dt;
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_NEWTAB",
                        "window.open( 'RptViewReport.aspx');", true);
                }
```

now the problem is GetData() method is taking ConnectionString from web.config which we want to assign dynamically.

Comment: Add your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: use class list model that return List<ClassType>for redlc

Comment: please share your Code also.

Comment: Post your code. You can't use an `rdlc` file as is, you probablu user a ReportViewer or another control. That control exposes the data sources through its "DataSources" property

Comment: Check the documentation, eg [Using the WebForms ReportViewer Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337091(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: Doesn't your TableAdapter expose a Connection property? You can change its connection string *before* calling `GetData`

Comment: But we want Dynamic Connction string i.e. it will change as per our user.